# Validate exist email using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

Does someone here know how to validate the exist email in Laravel? Not only valid email by it's domain, etc, but I need really exist email in this world.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's almost impossible to verify that the email exists on a server without verifying the registration. Laravel has [Email Verification](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification) built into the framework

Comment: That Email Verification only send the email without check it's exists or not 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an API For that like [Trumail](https://trumail.io/)

make this request:
`https://api.trumail.io/v2/lookups/<format>?email=<email>`

It will return some information about the email provided, one of this information is `deliverable` which takes the value `true` if it's a real email.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [emailable.com](https://app.emailable.com/) and create an account to get the API key

send a `GET` request to https://api.emailable.com/v1/verify?email=email@gmail.com&api_key=live_xxxxx

You should get a response like below

```
{
"accept_all": false,
"did_you_mean": null,
"disposable": false,
"domain": "gmail.com",
"duration": 0.036,
"email": "xxxx.email@gmail.com",
"first_name": null,
"free": true,
"full_name": null,
"gender": null,
"last_name": null,
"mx_record": "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com",
"reason": "accepted_email",
"role": false,
"score": 95,
"smtp_provider": "Google",
"state": "deliverable",
"tag": null,
"user": "email user"
}
```

When the `state` is `deliverable` then the email is valid and `undeliverable` means the email is invalid and cannot receive an email.